# Using File::read in a provider's default.rb in Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, lwrp

I am trying to create an LWRP that will call the resource that is defined within itself. My cookbook's structure is as follows:

[image]

In the machine cookbook's provider, I have a code snippet as follows:

```
require 'chef/provisioning'  # driver for creating machines
require '::File'

    def get_environment_json
      @@environment_template = JSON.parse(File::read(new_resource.template_path + "environment.json"))
      return @@environment_template
    end
```

The code is only trying to read a json file and I am using File::read for it.

I keep getting an error as follows:

### LoadError

cannot load such file -- ::File

Does anyone know how I can use File::read inside my LWRP's provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens becuase Chef already has a file resource. We have to use the Ruby File class in a recipe.We use ::File to use the Ruby File class to fix this issue. For example:

```
execute 'apt-get-update' do
  command 'apt-get update'
  ignore_failure true
  only_if { apt_installed? }
  not_if { ::File.exist?('/var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp') }
end
```

Source: https://docs.chef.io/ruby.html#ruby-class

Comment: While that will be an issue as well, the problem is in the require statement.

Answer (score 6):

OK, so the prior two answers are both half right.  You have two problems.
First, you can't require `::File` as it's already part of Ruby.  This is the cause of your error.

Second, if you call `File.read` you will grab Chef's `File` not ruby's.  You need to do a `::File.read` to use Ruby's File class.

Answer (score 0):

```
require '::File'
```

Is incorrect and is causing the LoadError. Delete this line. You don't need it. `File` is part of the Ruby core and doesn't need to be `require`d.

To further explain, the string argument to `require` represents the file name of the library you want to load. So, it should look like `require "file"`, or `require "rack/utils"`.

Comment: I thought it was included in core ruby too. If I don't have the require line, I get an error like this:

Error executing action `create` on resource 'amir-test-environments-inbound-machines[test]'
    ========================================================
    
    NoMethodError
    -------------
    undefined method `read' for Chef::Provider::File:Class

It was trying to look for the File class under Chef's Provider class. I fixed this by using

 @@environment_template = JSON.parse(::File::read(new_resource.template_path + "environment.json"))

It works fine now. Thanks for the help!